# c# object created in main view passed to partial view empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-4.5

C#, .Net 4.5, MVC 5

**Referring to XX1 and XX2 below (Main View):**

The object is initialized in the main controller. (Both the header and the Detial.)

I have added breakpoints at both XX1 and XX2 to confirm that that the initialized values are still there.

- No problem with XX1. The initialized values are there and it is
  passed to and received by the controller.
- XX2 have a problem. The initialized values are still there and is
  passed to, but a null object is somehow received by, the controller.

Why do the controller for the detail not pick up the passed parameters for it.

**Model:**

```
public class SampleNonRoutine
{
    public HeaderNonRoutine SampleHeader { get; set; }
    public List<DetailNonRoutine> SampleDetail { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}

public class HeaderNonRoutine
{
    public string Division { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Sample Title")]
    public string SampleTitle { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Retain Sample for")]
    public int RetainSample { get; set; }
}

public class DetailNonRoutine
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Sample Reference #")]
    public string SampleReference { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Sample Test")]
    public string SamplesTested { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Sample Assays")]
    public string SampleAssays { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

**For Parent View**

```
public ActionResult NonRoutineSamples(string SaveSend)
    {
        SampleNonRoutine sample = new SampleNonRoutine();
        sample.SampleHeader = new HeaderNonRoutine();
        sample.SampleDetail = new List<DetailNonRoutine>();
        sample.Comments = "Toets";

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            sample.SampleDetail.Add(new DetailNonRoutine { ID = i + 1, SampleReference = "", SamplesTested = "", SampleAssays = "" });
        }

        return View(sample);
    }
```

**For Partial Views:**

**Header (Partial View):**

```
    public ActionResult _HeaderNonRoutineSamples(HeaderNonRoutine model)
    {
//...some code
        PersonDetail pDetail = _db.ListPerson(_MePerson.First().Number.ToString());
        model.Name = pDetail.Name + " " + pDetail.Surname;
        model.Telephone = pDetail.PhoneWork;
        model.Division = pDetail.Division;
        model.RetainSample = 30;
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

**Detail:**

```
    public ActionResult _DetailNonRoutineSamples(List<DetailNonRoutine> model)
    {
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

**Views:**

**Main**

```
@model LaboratorySampleRegistration.Models.SampleNonRoutine
@{
ViewBag.Title = "NonRoutineSamples";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<h4>Non-Routine Samples</h4>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.Action("_HeaderNonRoutineSamples", "Home", Model.SampleHeader) XX1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.Action("_DetailNonRoutineSamples", "Home", Model.SampleDetail) XX2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div>
                    <span>
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comments, new { @class = "SampleRoutineComments" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <hr style="border-top:1px solid black !important;" />
            <p>
                <input id="SaveSend" name="SaveSend" type="submit" value="Send to Laboratory" class="btn btn-default" />
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

}

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: What are _XX1 and XX2_ that your referring to? (relate your question to the code)

Comment: Thank you @Stephen Muecke. Noted.

Comment: Then why have you changed it back?

Comment: @Stephan-Muecke     <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.Action("_HeaderNonRoutineSamples", "Home", Model.SampleHeader) XX1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.Action("_DetailNonRoutineSamples", "Home", Model.SampleDetail) XX2
        </td>
    </tr>

Comment: I was not sure if it was for information only or if it was incorrect

Comment: Found solution (edited code above). Assigned to session variable and cast it back to object. Why a list<T>  can not be passed to a partial view is still not clear.

Comment: I have rolled back the changes (answers go in Answers, not in the question) and I have rolled back your changes. Feel free to add your own answer and accept it.

Comment: But its not necessary to use a hack like `Session` and you can simply use `@Html.Action("_DetailNonRoutineSamples", "Home", new { model = Model.SampleDetail })`

Comment: Thank you Stephen. I will have a look.

Comment: Thank you Stephen it worked! +1